# Ruby Hash does not recognize its keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I populate a Ruby Hash with parsed Strings from a file. (I parse a freeradius log.)
Now I want to add filters to this script, but hash.has_key etc does not recognize keys, which are clearly inside the hash.

Script: radreport

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'
require 'yaml'

class AccountingEntry
    attr_accessor :attributes

    def initialize
        @attributes = Hash.new
    end

    def print
        puts self.to_yaml
    end
end

# ------------ Get Options ------------
options = {}
optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.banner = "Usage: radreport [options] file"
    opts.on( '-a', '--filter-attribute ATTRIBUTE', "Only show results where ATTRIBUTE is VALUE (Use with -fv)") do |attribute|
        options[:filter] = 1
        options[:filter_attr] = attribute
    end
    opts.on( '-v', '--filter-value VALUE', "Only show results where ATTRIBUTE is VALUE (Use with -fa)" ) do |value|
        options[:filter] = 1
        options[:filter_val] = value
    end
end
optparse.parse!

if (options[:filter] && !options[:filter_attr])
    puts "ERROR: Trying to filter results, but one option (-fa) is missing."
    exit
elsif (options[:filter] && options[:filter_val] == nil)
    puts "ERROR: Trying to filter results, but one option (-fv) is missing."
    exit
end

puts options.inspect

tmp = AccountingEntry.new

# ----------- Get File ----------------
ARGV.each do|f|
    if File.readable?(f)
        File.open(f).each do |line|
            if /(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d+\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4}/ =~ line
                if (options[:filter])
                    puts tmp.attributes.inspect
                    puts tmp.attributes.has_key?(options[:filter_attr])
                    if (tmp.attributes.key(options[:filter_attr]) == options[:filter_val])
                        tmp.print
                        puts "-------------------------------------------------- \n"
                    end
                elsif
                    tmp.print
                    puts "-------------------------------------------------- \n"
                end
                tmp = AccountingEntry.new
            end
            if /\A\s*.*\s=\s".*"/ =~ line
                tmp.attributes.store(line.scan(/\A\s*(.*)\s=\s".*"/)[0], line.scan(/\A\s*.*\s=\s"(.*)"/)[0])
            elsif /\A\s*.*\s=\s.*/ =~ line
                tmp.attributes.store(line.scan(/\A\s*(.*)\s=\s.*/)[0], line.scan(/\A\s*.*\s=\s(.*)/)[0])
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Input file: detail-test

```
Mon Jun 16 13:26:19 2014
    User-Name = "testuser"
    Timestamp = 1402917979

Mon Jun 16 13:26:24 2014
    User-Name = "testuser"
    Timestamp = 1402917984
```

Output:

```
$ ./radreport -a User-Name -v testuser detail-test
{:filter=>1, :filter_attr=>"User-Name", :filter_val=>"testuser"}
{}
false
{["User-Name"]=>["testuser"], ["Timestamp"]=>["1402917979"]}
false
{["User-Name"]=>["testuser"], ["Timestamp"]=>["1402917984"]}
false
```

Normally the output should be true for the last two entries and after that the entry should be printed.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. Maybe it's the problem, that the values are also in brackets?

Comment: You appear to be populating the hash with single-element arrays as keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to determine from the amount of extra code, but it appears that you are trying to access the keys via symbols (i.e. `:filter`) when they are stored as strings (i.e. `"filter"`).

This function will convert them.

```
my_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But i had to modify two more thinks in my code: 1) I need to convert options[:filter_attr] with .to_sym too. 2) I have to store strings and not single element arrays.